# set height of icon Image template programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I have one column in my datagrid which contains Icons.
for this I have one celltemplate added to column programatically.

```
var imageFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Image));
                    imageFactory.SetBinding(System.Windows.Controls.Image.SourceProperty, imageBinding);
                    imageFactory.SetValue(System.Windows.Controls.Image.StretchProperty, Stretch.None);
                    if (config.Font != null)
                    {
                        double height = config.Font.Size;
                        imageFactory.SetValue(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty, height);

                    }
                    var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate { VisualTree = imageFactory };
                    statusColumn.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;
                    view.DataGrid.Columns.Add(statusColumn);
```

when I set Height property externally it **crops the image** instead of resizing image to 'height' value.

how to set image height to specific value.
please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used BitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight and it solved my problem. :)

```
bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                bitmapImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
                bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = font.Size <= 9 ? font.Size + 2 : font.Size;
                bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmapImage.EndInit();
                bitmapImage.Freeze();
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    double size = 14.0;
    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("MyIcon.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

    FrameworkElementFactory icon = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
    icon.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, bmp);
    icon.SetValue(Image.WidthProperty, size);
    icon.SetValue(Image.HeightProperty, size);
```

UPDATE try this

```
   Style sBase = (Style)this.Resources["BaseButtonStyle"];
   Style sNew = new Style(typeof(Image), sBase);
   sNew.Setters.Add(new Setter(HeightProperty, 20d));
```

REFERENCE
[See this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9ee94f4c-457d-4c72-9055-e1973bfd0b6b/)

Comment: I have tried same above, setting HeightPrtoperty. but still doesn't work

Comment: actually my problem is Icon image is going to be loaded dynamically any time during execution. so I just have FrameworkElementFactory for now at time of Loading. now, I tried to setimageFactory.SetValue(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty, height); but it didn't work. it crops dynamically loeaded image icon.

Comment: Worked for me and my related question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379995/show-image-in-dynamically-generated-datagrid-columns-in-wpf/59390358#59390358