# Show Image in dynamically generated DataGrid.Columns in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've to pivot information data from a query, and show images based on value read from the underlying database.

Let's say I have this data out of my query:

```
Identifiant|ProcessId|AlarmLevel
  BOUDA25  |   100   |    1
  BOUDA25  |   110   |    1
  BOUDA25  |   130   |    1
  BOUDA25  |   205   |    2
  BOUDA25  |   210   |    2
```

I now want to make the following WPF DataGrid display the actual images represented by `images/circle_orange.ico`, etc.
[image: Programmatically Generated]

So far my code resembles this:

```
private void PopulateGrid(IEnumerable<AlarmeViewModel> alarmes) {        
    // Used to pivot the information data
    var table=new DataTable();

    // Generates the columns based on rows
    table.Columns.Add("Identifiant");
    table.Columns.Add("=>");

    alarmes.ForEach(a => a.Processes.ForEach(pid => table.Columns.Add(columnName:pid, type typeof(string))));

    // Generates the rows
    var images = new string[] {
        "images/circle_grey.ico",
        "images/circle_orange.ico",
        "images/circle_yellow.ico",
        "images/circle_red.ico",
        "images/circle_green.ico"        
    };

    alarmes.ForEach(a => {
        var row = table.NewRow();
        row[0] = a.Identifiant

        for(int i=0; i<a.Niveaux.Count; row[a.Processes[i]]=images[a.AlarmLevel[1]], i++);

        table.Rows.Add(row);
    });

    // Refreshes the DataGrid content
    alarmDataGrid.BeginInit();
    alarm.DataGrid.ItemsSource=table.DefaultView;
    alarmDataGrid.EndInit();
}
```

Now I'm stuck since three days to make those image display through an ImageSource binding.

I tried to let the DataGrid autogenerate the columns by itself, and I also tried by adding them in the code behind from the accepted answer of this question:

- [**How do I show image in wpf datagrid column programmatically?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951839/how-do-i-show-image-in-wpf-datagrid-column-programmatically)

And this one also:

- [**WPF add datagrid image column possible?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683314/wpf-add-datagrid-image-column-possible)

And I just can't get it.  I know I'm close, but still missing the obvious, I guess.

Comment: one more similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40358111/1506454

Comment: @ASh  This is very helpful!  Actually just need to figure out from that how I can make my converter read the alarm level from the rows so it assigns the correct image.  Way simpler than what I had first.  I think I'll update my code sample to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event and programmatically create a `DataGridTemplateColumn` that contains an `Image` element. Try this:

```
private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName != "Identifiant" && e.PropertyName != "=>")
    {
        FrameworkElementFactory image = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
        image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding(e.PropertyName));

        e.Column = new DataGridTemplateColumn
        {
            CellTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = image },
            Header = e.PropertyName
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to do anything special with the image files or just letting them as Content/Copy Always is fine?  Because I feed the relative path to the image file as my screenshot shows, and when I use the code sample provided, it won't display any image or value.  Like the cell is empty.  I got to deliver this feature by next Friday, and I've worked on it since last Sunday.  Growing nervous...

Comment: Besides, when using the IValueConverter from the XAML DataTemplate as a DataGrid.Resources, my converter gets called, but it doesn't seem to work as I expected, namely the object value parameter is the whole row in the form of a DataRowView, instead of just a cell value at time.  So it's nearly impossible to work around.  I'm really at a dead end now.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you use the coverter? You shouldn't need one.

Comment: I'm no longer using it with your approach.  I went all the way to your solution, but there must be something I'm doing wrong because it won't display any image.  Even after I copied and pasted your code directly into my AutoGeneratingColumn implementation.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event handler is actually invoked?

Comment: Ayup!  It is.  Just put a breakpoint into it to double verify though I was sure.

Comment: Are you sure that the image paths are valid? Try with another path and image.

Comment: Pretty sure, since I use the same images for other XAML pre-defined columns in the app and they display just fine.  It's really just with the auto-generating columns I've an issue.  I tried replacing `images/circle_grey.ico` by `icon_exit.png` and removing the `images/` from `circle_orange.ico`.  I even tried restarting my computer in case VS has cached something or the like.  Images are set as Content/Copy Always.  Should I consider to set them as Resource/Do Not Copy?  I'm lost here.  Your guidance is appreciated.  You bring hope!  :D

Comment: Both resources/do not copy and content should work. There is something else going on in your code. You should provide a minimal repo.

Comment: With your email, I could actually grant you access to the app.  I'm that desperate.  :(  Otherwise, I will create a simpler app and reproduce this section of code in it and create a minimal repo as suggested.  Thx from the bottom of my heart for your help!

Comment: Please do the latter: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I created a GitHub repository for this with a tiny app that reproduces the issue:  https://github.com/WillMarcouiller/AutoGeneratingColumnWpf

Comment: @WillMarcouiller: As I expected, your image paths are invalid. Replace "images" with "../images" and it works, e.g.: `"../images/circle_grey.ico"`.

Comment: Hell yeah!  But why was the path incorrect?  I mean, when deployed, there's an Images folder created at same level as the executable file.  Hopefully it'll work when deployed.  Do you have a clue as to how to resize the image, for the icon to be smaller in the grid rather than just resize the actual images?

Comment: The path is relative to the `UserControl` which is located in the `UserControls` folder. You may want to read up on [pack URIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf). They let you identify resources using paths relative to the root of the assembly.

Comment: You definitely made my day!  My sincerest thanks for your support!  +1 and accepted answer.  :)